# How can I reuse a custom function created in one Google Sheets App Script in multiple files without copying and pasting?

Tags: google-sheets

I am using google sheets App Script.
I got 4 different files
I created an custom function in the App Script on the one of the files.
I want to use the same function in another file instead, of copy and paste it to the other App scripts.
To avoid make every update 4 time each update

Thanks !

I already tried to do import the function with the option Data>Named Functions,
and it didnt worked well .